# Type Inference of Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I am new to Ocaml. Here is one question in my class:

let f a b c d e = e.(  if e.(1) then a b else b d  )

We were asked to inferred the type of "a". I think it is an int, because this if operation should return an int to be the index of e array. But my answer is wrong. Can anyone help me to analyze this ? Thank you very much !

Comment: note that if you want to check your answer for this sort of question, you can quickly launch utop and, type your expression in it, and watch the type ocaml inferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `if` is either `a b` or `b d`. Since the expression `a b` must return an int (as you say), `a` must be a *function* that accepts one argument and returns an int. So `a` is not an int but a function.

The type of the parameter of `a` is also part of the type of `a`. To determine this type, note that `b` is also a function that returns an int (as you can tell from the subexpression `b d`). So `a` is a function that accepts one argument that is a function and returns int. Since there is nothing in the code to limit the type of `d`, `b` can be any function that accepts one argument and returns an int. Let's call the type of b's argument `'t`. Note that this type can be different for different calls to `f`. So then the type of `a` is `('t -> int) -> int`, where the corresponding type of `b` is `'t -> int` and the type of `d` is `'t`.

This is all pretty complicated. Possibly there's a typo in your transcription. Or maybe it's good to work out a complicated example :-)

Comment: Jeffrey, if I change the   "then a b"   to   " then abc"  does it change the 'a' to a function that taking two parameters and return an int ? Or it should be seen as "a" is still taking b as argument and c is the argument of b?

Comment: The meaning of `a b c` that `a` takes two parameters. If you want `c` to be the argument of `b` you have to write `a (b c)`. But there's quite a bit more to say about functions and parameters. You should perhaps look at an OCaml tutorial. (Look for *Currying* and *partial application* for example.)

Answer (score 0):

**the above statement is equivalent to:**

fun f(a,b,c,d) = e[ if e[1] then a(b) else b(d) ]

__

Note:

1. "if e[1] then a(b) else b(d)" : this should be an int, as it act as the index of e array. function will return the same type, so Type of a(b) and b(d) are equal and should return integer.
2. e[1] = this should be boolean, that means e is an array of boolean.

**Hence what we concluded**

e : array of boolean

a : function returns an integer

b : function returns an integer.

we can't further type inference for c and d.